# MSDeploy skip delete not working

Tags: asp.net, msdeploy

I want to skip the deletion of the files on the \log folder on a web application running on a IIS virtual path: 'website\v2\service'

I tried the command line:

```
"msdeploy.exe" -source:package='Package.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='https://host   /MsDeploy.axd',userName='####',password='####',authtype='Basic',includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -skip:skipaction='Delete',objectname='dirPath',absolutepath='\\log' -setParamFile:"SetParameters.xml"   -allowUntrusted
```

But the files on website\v2\service\log folder are still being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters file specified in the operation setting `-setParamFile:"SetParameters.xml"` – it's possible the settings in that file are overriding the `-skip` setting in your example command.